# RB-Tree: search execution time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory, time-complexity, red-black-tree

I must implement an interval tree using RB-trees for an "algorithm and data structures" class project, so it was asked to plot insertion and search `T(n)`. I know that this function must be upper-bounded by a logarithmic curve, indeed the plot shows exactly this, but i've still some doubt about the "strange function trend". I've wrote a cycle that inserts a random interval and searches it into the tree at the same step for each value of `0 < N < 100000`, this is the result:

[image]

Is it right to expect similar trend?

Comment: I forgot to say that this plot comes from a testbench version where the time is computed incrementing a counter for each search function iteration; this is done due to the fact that runtime environment should misrepresent real execution time, so i'm sure that, if a problem exists, that is into data structure/testbench

Comment: check if the tree has minimum values for n = 2^k-1 because in that case the tree should be prefectly balanced hence will have minimum search time for random searches. when you search for T(n) should be average over a significant amount of searches.

Comment: yes, i'm sure that my tree is balanced, because insert's T(n) is pretty close to logarithmic behavior. moreover, i've tried to check for each insertion/search cycle that rb tree property height<=2*black height is respected and test not fails. I'm also trying to insert in-order intervals values and search for an interval that i'm sure can't exists (eg. Integer.MAX_VALUE , Integer.MAX_VALUE) in order to force the algorithm to visit each level until leaves, but results are still the same

Comment: Then your graph seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly reasonable to expect.

Insertions into a red/black tree have two components: a baseline Θ(log n) component for descending down to a leaf in order to insert an element, and then some additional "fixup" work to maintain the red/black tree invariants. It turns out that this second component is amortized O(1), meaning that *on average* only a constant amount of work is required for the fixup, but every now and then the fixup work increases.

If you've seen the connection between red/black trees and 2-3-4 trees, this might be a bit easier to understand. Insertions in a 2-3-4 tree typically stop by simply adding a key to a leaf node. Every now and then, you have to split a 4 node and propagate a key up to a node higher in the tree, which usually stops immediately. However, every so often, you'll have to split a leaf, then split a node above that, then propagate a key two layers up. The typical pattern you'll get when doing insertions like this is that you'll get a series of fast operations, then one that's a little slower, then some more fast operations, then one that's a little slower, then some more fast operations, then one that's even slower than the others, etc. You seem to be getting this in your plot, so I don't think that's anything to worry about.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i've read this too late but it's very complete....further, i've achieved maximum vote so the graphic should be right....so, vote up and thanks the same!!!